# How can I programatically access a web API that is secured with SSO?

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api, saml, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a web application that contains few APIs. The web application also has a HTML page were these APIs are consumed to render the UI. The web application hosted internally but secured with Microsoft Azure AD authetication.
I am trying to build a C# console application that can consume the APIs directly, without opening the website on a browser. 
Is it possible to access the Web APIs directly from c# console app?
I understand that when a browser is used to access the SSO content, it will manage the authentication process. However I do not know how can I do that from a C# application. Are there any libraries released by Microsoft to deal with Azure AD authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read Microsoft Identity Platform application scenarios?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios

There is a lot of the quickstarts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant and tutorials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-aspnet-daemon-web-app

Microsoft released a lot of the Azure AD authentication libraries, most of them are named MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library).